# Move-Item while renaming files and "cleaning" the file-name using regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using a script to move files from one directory to another.  It's also stripping out some text via some RegEx work.  However, while I have a relatively short script, I think I can still do better.  Below is my sample script.

```
$Source = "C:\temp\test\source"
$Dest = "C:\temp\test\dest"

get-childitem $Source\*.* | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}IP\.',''} -WhatIf
move-item $Source\*.* $Dest -WhatIf
```

Now, this works but, as you can see, it's two lines and I'm pretty sure it can be done in one.  I think I'm "not getting my money's worth" out of the `move-item` command.  How would I accomplish this without having to do a separate `rename-item` command?  If you need more info, let me know and I'll see what I can do.  I'm rather new to PS and RegEx stuff.  I deal more with batch files but I don't think it can handle RegEx.  That's why I'm attempting PS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex replace on the destination parameter of the Move-Item cmdlet. That should do the job for you. Adapting your example:

```
$Source = "C:\temp\test\source"
$Dest = "C:\temp\test\dest"

get-childitem $Source | Foreach-Object {
  Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$Dest\$($_.name -replace '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}IP\.','')" -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: I was so close!  I was messing around with something similar and I had the parenthesis (and a few other things) in the wrong place.  At any rate, that worked a treat!  Thank you much!